# Documentum NPE when running as jar

Tags: jar, nullpointerexception, documentum

I'm writing a simple application to create a Documentum folder structure from a directory structure on disk.  When I run the application through SpringSource Tool Suite, it works fine.  When I package it as a jar, with all dependencies, and run it, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.documentum.fc.common.impl.preferences.PreferencesManager.locateMainPersistentStore(PreferencesManager.java:372) 
at com.documentum.fc.common.impl.preferences.PreferencesManager.readPersistentProperties(PreferencesManager.java:333)
    at com.documentum.fc.common.impl.preferences.PreferencesManager.<init>(PreferencesManager.java:41)
    at com.documentum.fc.common.DfPreferences.initialize(DfPreferences.java:64)
    at com.documentum.fc.common.DfPreferences.getInstance(DfPreferences.java:43)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSimpleDbor.getDefaultDbor(DfSimpleDbor.java:78)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSimpleDbor.<init>(DfSimpleDbor.java:66)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient$ClientImpl.<init>(DfClient.java:344)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.<clinit>(DfClient.java:754)
```

Here is the line in my code where this error occurs:

```
IDfClient client = DfClient.getLocalClient();
```

The jar includes the dfc.properties file, which I specify on the command line using

```
-Ddfc.properties.file=dfc.properties.dev
```

For the record, the full command line looks like this (slightly anonymized):

```
java -Ddfc.properties.file=dfc.properties.dev -jar MyTest-jar-with-dependencies.jar baseDirectory baseDocumentumFolder
```

Thanks much for your time!

Comment: Does your jar include the other configuration files normally located with the dfc.properties file?

Comment: As near as I can tell it includes everything.

Comment: It sounds like a classpath issue to me.  I'm wondering if your IDE has some additional paths included.

Comment: Have you gotten any further or have any more information to share?  I'm interested to know what the resolution is in the end.